# google maps not showing in update panel ,No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#

Font from origin 'http://fonts.gstatic.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:17136' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom fonts from Google CDN? if so, the simplest solution is to download the fonts instead of using google CDN. This bug usually occurs due to errors in Google CDN and you cannot fix that at your end.

Comment: is it possible for you to post the code snippet, or create any plunker (plnkr.co)?